# Nested templates and static member initialization

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create an inner template class that will be dependent on the outer class.
I'm having trouble defining its static members:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct B { 
  template<typename T3> 
  struct C { 
      static T3 m_c;
  }; 
  static T1 * pT1;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
template<typename T3>
T3 B<T1,T2>::C<T3>::m_c;

template<typename T1, typename T2> 
T1 * B<T1,T2>::pT1 = &B<T1,T2>::C<T2>::m_c;
```

I'm getting:
a.cc:35: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
a.cc:35: error: '::m_c' has not been declared

How do I define it?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks pretty ok to me. What compiler are you using?

Comment: The code compiles cleanly using VC9, VC10, and [Comeau Online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/).

Comment: Sorry the code got massed-up when I posted it.
Now there is the correct code.

Comment: it still compiles fine for me. I just tested it on 5 different compilers: borland, vc10, mingw-gcc-4.5.2, digital mars c++, and Clang. What compiler *are* you using that's rejecting that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your compiler fails at parsing the `<` sign as the opening bracket of template declaration. Try to tell it explicitly that it is a template, not a less-than operator:

```
template<typename T3>
T3 B<T1,T2>::template C<T3>::m_c;
```